# Using a trademarked name as the partial name of a new business

Tags: trademark, innocent-infringement

If a company named "XYZ LLC" has the name "XYZ" trademarked, am I infringing if I incorporate an LLC with the name "XYZ" partially in it, e.g., "XYZ Entertainment LLC" ?

Comment: Is it a similar industry? Is there any similarity in business dealings? Could a person reasonably associate the new name with the old business?

Comment: Thanx for answering Ron, to answer your reply, no it is completely different industries (one is virtual assistant/health care, and the other is a mail order products company with no real online presence-which further aids in preventing any type of consumer confusion) In light of this info, what do you think now?? (I appreciate your time and expertise, I read your profile - you are a very accomplished guy!)